# WPF Automatically Change Width and Height

Tags: wpf, layout

I have media element, image, two marquee text and one row text. How can i set for automatically change height and width? For example; WrapPanel or Viewbow, exc.

Actually, i'm already done but i used Grid row and column. When i change resolution to good resolution; specially text will be not bigger. will be bigger but not as it should be.

I'm really tired about WPF layout! I can't understand :)

EDIT: i can use DevExpress WPF products, i have licence.

Thanks and regards.

EDIT: Current XAML:

```
        <RowDefinition Height="422" />

        <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="70"/>
        <!--<RowDefinition Height="121*"/>-->
        <RowDefinition/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

        <ColumnDefinition Width="424*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="129*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <MediaElement Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,20
                   ,0,0"
        Name="myMediaElement" Stretch="Fill"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"   >
        <MediaElement.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <MediaTimeline Source="C:\a\p.mov" Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement"  
             RepeatBehavior="Forever" />

                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </MediaElement.Triggers>
        <MediaElement.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="6" Color="#FFD8D8D8"/>
        </MediaElement.Effect>
    </MediaElement>
    <StackPanel   Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <Image  x:Name="imgLogo"  Source="C:\a\a.png"  Margin="0,10,0,0" MaxHeight="200" MaxWidth="200" >
            <Image.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="#FFD6CDCD"/>
            </Image.Effect>
        </Image>
```

DX doest not support this subject. Specially text is really problem for me.

Comment: Please post your existing xaml

Comment: http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx

Comment: Wow, you can search, ha? It's really funny :)